# Opposite of Android Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE?

Tags: android, window

Whats the opposite of

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
in Android?

Simply trying to restore the original title bar after removing it using the above code.

(without restarting my activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requestWindowFeature(int)` method from Activity class actually calls `getWindow().requestFeature(int)`.

From Android developer resource for `Window` class says the following about `requestFeature(int)` method:

> Enable extended screen features. This must be called before setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it is before setContentView(). If not called, no extended features will be available. You can not turn off a feature once it is requested. You canot use other title features with FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE.

[Link to resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29)

Comment: Yea, the answer is that there is no such thing.

Comment: I actually jumped ahead of myself all together and don't want to use requestWindowFeature() at all as I had only ASSUMED it was what I wanted before actually testing it. But I don't know how to delete this question.